# Controlling the AutoScroll behavior on Panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, panel

I have a set of controls inside of a Panel and set the AutoScroll property of the panel to True so I get the Vertical ScrollBar but when I slide the bar is not smooth and if some of the upper controls inside the panel have the focus the bar return to the top.

I read some about and found a solution on

[smooth scroll with autoscroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714585/smooth-scroll-with-autoscroll)

Which work Ok but uses a lot of resources, I see it on Windows Task Manager, one of the processors goes about 60%, so I think is something wrong with this.

There's another way to met the same goal?

I tried to put my own VerticalScrollBar unsuccessfully. :(

Comment: You might want to look at [My proposed solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922233/control-addrange-is-slow/23023207#23023207) to that problem using current, relevant .Net Windows UI technologies.

Comment: what kind of controls are being scrolled?  I have one which scrolls up to 120 controls with no problem; none of them can get the focus though.

Comment: @Plutonix Is about 16 UserControls with a GroupBox with 7 Checkboxes, one TextBox and one Button each.

Comment: The link post is old and doesnt show the code which might hide all sorts of stuff.  I just created a UC with a TB, Btn and 2 Checks, added 30 of them to an Autoscrolling Panel and it works fine (ie smooth) with zero code to do anything scroll related.  The only code in my real app for scrolling is to implement mouse wheel scrolling when when the mouse is over it (ie it doesnt have focus).  Are you trying to do something like scroll whole UC items into view?

Comment: Did you tried to write some on the upper TextBox and then move down the ScrollBar? The issue appears when some control have the focus, so the AutoScroll try to show that control and don't let you move the ScrollBar.